# Removing comment form consent from Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In order to remove the consent field from the comment form on blog posts the following filter is added to my child themes function.php:

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'unset_consent_field');
function unset_consent_field($fields){
    if(isset($fields['cookies']))
       unset($fields['cookies']);
       return $fields;

}
```

The consent field remains however. Replacing 'cookies' with 'url' successfully removes the URL field so im not sure why its not working for the cookies field.

Any ideas what could be causing this and what the solution is?

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox can be removed under Wordpress Settings -> Privacy